# Problems with recurrent neural net working with time steps on Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to design a recurrent classificatory network with Keras. I have analyzed key characteristics of the frames of a video, and from them I want to identify when certain events occur during the video.

Specifically, I have a matrix (30 x 2) for each frame, which represents the positions of various given objects. From these positions, I would like the network to detect 4 different events, as well as in which frames they occur.

As an example, suppose I have the position of 30 cars in each frame already detected, and I want the network to learn to detect the frames in which:

1. a car stops
2. a car starts
3. two cars collide
4. a car turns

In each frame, one or none of these events can occur (category 0), but not more than one.

Something remarkable is that to identify these 4 events it is necessary to know both the data of the previous frames and those of the later ones. For example, to know that two cars collide, it is necessary to know that beforehand both were in motion, as well as that after the collision neither moves.

Following this example, and just to clarify, suppose I have a sample of 100 frames, in which there is a crash at frames 4 and 75, a stop at 12, a start at 37, and turns at 3, 30, and 60. It would have an input of 100x30x2, and an output of 100x1.

After several hours, I get the feeling that I am not understanding something well in the way of indicating to Keras how he is the model.

So far I have been trying the following, with variations in the number of LSTM layers and the number of classification neurons:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(30, 2)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['SparseCategoricalAccuracy'])
```

I have also tried to introduce the variation

```
model3.add(layers.LSTM(100, input_shape=(30, 2), return_sequences=True))
```

so that you take into account that not only is the final output valid, but if I don't add a `flatten` it doesn't work, and I deduce that I don't understand the matter well.

***Edit 1:***

After your advice, I have now the following model:

I start with the dataset, stored in an input `xp` and an output `yp`. Here I print the sizes of both variables:

```
xp.shape, yp.shape

((203384, 25, 2), (203384, 1))
```

Then I'm encoding `yp` with `keras.utils`, and I change the shape of each input element from a (25x2) matrix to a (1x50) vector:

```
n = len(xp)    
yp_encoded = keras.utils.to_categorical(yp)
xp_reshaped = xp[0:n,:].reshape(n,1,50)
print(n, xp_reshaped.shape, yp_encoded.shape)

203384, (203384, 1, 50), (203384, 5)
```

After, I define the model as we talked, with just LSTM layers

```
batch_size = 10    
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, 1, 50), activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, stateful=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(5, stateful=True, activation = 'softmax'))
model.summary()


Model: "sequential_140"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 lstm_184 (LSTM)             (10, 1, 100)              58800     
                                                                 
 lstm_185 (LSTM)             (10, 5)                   2120      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 60,920
Trainable params: 60,920
Non-trainable params: 0
```

So, as I understand, I have a LSTM model with an input of `(batch_size, 1, 100)` elements, that I should fit with an output of `(batch_size, 5)`.

Then, I do the model compilation, and the fit:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['SparseCategoricalAccuracy'])
model.fit(xp_reshaped, yp_encoded, epochs = 5, batch_size = batch_size, shuffle = False)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 5 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [10,5].
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to solve classification problem - classify frames as events with classes: start, stop, turn, collide and the 0 class (nothing happens). You've chosen the right approach - LSTMs, though your archtitecture is not good.

All your layers should be LSTMs with `stateful=True` and `return_sequences=True`, you should transform your target variable to one-hot encoding, set last layer's activation to softmax, it's output shape will be (n_frames, 4).

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your answer. I've been trying to apply your advice, but I have problems to the connections and dimensions.

When I set 'stateful = True', it requires me to set a batch size as well. Which batch size should I get? Maybe 1x50x2 and feed the system with one matrix at each step, but in order? 

I have problems to understand the one hot encoding dimensions too. If my understanding is correct, that should lead me with a row with 4 zeros and 1 one for each result I want to get, that will lead to probabilities when training...

Comment: I've tried the following arquitecture:
`model2 = keras.Sequential()
model2.add(layers.LSTM(50, batch_input_shape=(1, 30, 2), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model2.add(layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model2.add(layers.Dense(5, activation = 'softmax'))
model2.summary()`

which leads to a summary:
 `lstm_40 (LSTM) - (1, 30, 50) - 10600     
 dense_68 (Dense) - (1, 30, 32) - 1632                                                        
 dense_69 (Dense) - (1, 30, 5) - 165`

Comment: You should try a few batch size values - 1 and something like 8, 16, 32 or 64, depending on your data. Your one-hot-encoding understanding is correct. You should've used only LSTM layers (which is valid architecture), and don't forget to set relu as activation to your LSTMs

Comment: Sorry to ask you this many questions.
I think now I got your original explanation, so I'm working with this arquitecture:
`model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(n, 1, 100), activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, stateful=True))
model.add(layers.Dense(5, activation = 'sigmoid'))
` 
where `n` is the bach size. I've reformated the input matrixes to rows because the second input results in the output parameters I get for every LSTM neuron (I just want one).

Comment: So now, I have inputs of (1, 1, 100) (for the test with single date batches, `n` = 1) and a one hot encoded target of (1, 1, 5) for each of them. When I try to fit, I get the following error:

 `ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[2], expected a dimension of 1, got 5 for '{{node Squeeze}} = Squeeze[T=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[-1]](IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,1,5].`

I'm using the same model compile as before, and also tried `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: You don't need Dense layers at all. All your layers should be LSTMs

Comment: Still can't make it work, I have the same error over and over.
'model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(100, batch_input_shape=(n, 1, 100), activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True, stateful=True))
model.add(layers.LSTM(5, stateful=True, activation = 'softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'Adam', metrics = ['SparseCategoricalAccuracy'])
model.fit(tx, ty, epochs = 5, batch_size = n, shuffle = False)
'
'tx.shape, ty.shape = (10, 1, 100) (10, 5)'

Comment: I'm sorry to be annoying but I'm quite desesperate. Can't make the model fit, and I don't know what is the problem with the dimensions

Comment: You should check your final layer's output shape by calling model.summary(). It should be compatible with your target

Comment: I do! I have in the summary ` lstm_183 (LSTM) - (10, 5) - 2120` in the last layer, and when I try to do `model.fit(tx, ty, epochs = 5, batch_size = n, shuffle = False)` I get that error. Of course, `ty.shape` returns (10, 5) as output

Comment: Shapes are equal. There could be something with NN's architecture, please provide full code, don't forget to add there a few shape assertions for insurance

Comment: I have edited the question to show it clearer and make it easier to read. Really, thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Now I get it. You are using wrong metric, use simple accuracy. And you have a little data misshape. Look, you wanted to get predictions for each frame, so your output should be of shape (batch size, n frames, 5).